# JSON for .NET Framework 1.1

Tags: json, .net-1.1

I can see that JSON used a lot for .NET 2.0 and higher.

Is there a JSON library I can use for .NET Framework v1.1 ?

Comment: Why are you still using a 9-year-old framework?

Comment: Though I understand and align with @SLaks reaction, not everyone is fortunate enough to be able to discard a framework with which their product so tightly relies on.

Comment: I can sympathize being stuck on an older framework, or just old technologies. Try as we might; the mighty power of bureaucracy prevents progress with moving on.

Comment: @SLaks: can you imagine i spent my last month to port 2.0 application to 1.1. So if somebody is asking help for older framework just help him out straight away to ease the stress he/she already has :s

Answer (score 1):

There have been a few attempts to bring JSON to .NET 1.1. Given such an old Framework version you are on, most of those attempts have been abandoned by people moving on with the next version of the .NET Framework (which I encourage you to do).

Barring that, you could try [JSON Object Serializer](http://jsonserializer.codeplex.com/). I'm sure it isn't perfect, but it is open source - allowing you to make contributions and bug fixes for it yourself.

Comment: Is there deserializer or parser for .NET1.1

Comment: @Peter yes, I linked to one you can try in my answer.

Comment: Yes, It work for serialization .NET objects to JSON. But it doesn't has parser.