# JSON string to XML string

Tags: c#, asp.net, serialization, type-conversion, asp.net-1.1

I want to know **how can I convert JSON string to XML string** in **ASP.NET 1.1**

I can not use third party library for some restriction.

Any suggestion would be a big help.

Comment: ASP.NET 1.1? you should migrate to a newer framework!

Comment: @Jordi . I wish that is in my hand..

Comment: I hope you will be able to upgrade in the future. My sincere support

Comment: But currently I am stuck in this conversion stuff..and its killing..

Comment: Sorry but can I just ask, why on earth would you be prevented from upgrading? Is there a technical reason why this would be necessary?

Comment: No, not a technical reason..Its a combination of many things..it will need more guys to develop the whole things..which means more investment and other aspects too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to deserialize this JSON into an object and then, serialize this object again in XML. I think this is a simple approach.

Comment: Whatever way I am finding to convert Json to object are for framework 3.5 and above..Can you suggest for 1.1, if any

Comment: I'm afraid the problem is being in asp.net 1.1, I've found this other question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7207238/json-for-net-framework-1-1) that ask for using JSON in version 1.1 and they encourage to upgrade the framework, but it seems this is not in your hands. What you can always do, and it's not a good idea, is to manually parse the JSON string and build a translated XML Object. It's not a good idea and makes me cry! sorry :(

Comment: you can always show that to your CTO: http://cdn.memegenerator.net/instances/400x/29701086.jpg :)

Comment: Cant we serialize the json object to xml in Jquery???That will be framework independent..

Comment: I've fount [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1773550/xml-json-conversion-in-javascript) question that talks about XML/JSON conversion in jQuery, maybe it works for you! :)